# is it possible to send HTTPS request with multiple cookies to the server? Cloudfront nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

Here I created signed cookies(3 cookies) to access the cloudfront,but I wanted to know, how to send these cookies in the https request header to access the content in cloudfront in nodejs

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem with my answer?

Comment: I used header in https request to send the cookies, Thanks for the answer

Comment: Great, glad I could help! Can you please consider accepting this answer, if it had helped you to solve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to send cookies to your CloudFront distribution. Here is how to pass a cookie with your request:

`curl -b 'session=session_id' -b 'another=cookie' https://yourdistribution.cloudfront.net`

The full header that curl sets for this request looks like this `Cookie: session=session_id; another=cookie`

Best, Stefan